# how to open/convert .ost file (Microsoft Outlook email folder) on linux

Tags: email, conversion, file-format

How can I convert (or open) `.ost` file (Microsoft Outlook email folder) on linux ?

Ideally, I would like to read it with `Mutt`. But mutt does not seem to understand this format. Therefore I would like to convert it into something readable such as mbox or mdir format.

Are there such conversion tools on linux ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few tools which help with interoperability with Outlook files:

- [`libpff`](https://github.com/libyal/libpff), which includes a `pffexport` program which can extract data from OST (and other) files;
- [Evolution](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evolution) has a PST import plugin which can handle OST files;
- [`libpst`](https://www.five-ten-sg.com/libpst/), which can convert PST files to mbox files, but I don’t know whether it can handle OST files.

`pffexport` should at least allow you to view the contents of the emails.

Comment: pst, nst and ost look like identical file formats.

Comment: @MichałLeon yes, they use the same format, only the contents differ.